# Refresh data every 2 minutes or show when updated at server retrofit

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I already searched how refresh data in recycler view using retrofit library to get data but unfortunately I can't find anything.

Could you please put me on right direction where I can find information.

I got App when customer make order and see order status, how to make when person update order status, example from 0 in 1 in database, so that's mean it's changed value but retrofit only loaded data when status is 0. How to make when App recognice a value is updated in database and show to customer not 0 status but 1.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
private Handler mRepeatHandler;
private Runnable mRepeatRunnable;
private final static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 2000;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     mRepeatHandler = new Handler();
     mRepeatRunnable = new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
               //Put the piece of code which is getting data from server.

               mRepeatHandler.postDelayed(mRepeatRunnable, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
          };

     mRepeatHandler.postDelayed(mRepeatRunnable, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **DiffUtil**, an Android support library utility class, which helps to ease out the process of finding which item changed in a list of data. It helps to calculate the difference between an old list and a new list and trigger updates to list items.

Here is the example [link](https://therubberduckdev.wordpress.com/2017/11/09/handle-data-change-in-recyclerview-using-diffutil/)